# Widget that shows categories with posts numbers

Tags: posts, categories, widgets

Is there any solution to show categories with posts numbers like 'Archives' widget without changing the font size?

UPD0: Sorry if my question is not clear. What I want? We have a pretty nice widget, which generates the following Archives like this:

[image]

The question is, how we can get the same view for categories? Like this:

```
Categories
My Category (12)
Another category (16)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far. Please add the code that you have so far, working or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is no coding involved here. Wordpress has already a build in widget for this function. If you go to the "Widgets" screen. you'll see that there are a widget called Categories

[image: Screenshot1]

You can drag and drop that to your sidebar where you need to display the widget. When you've done that, the widget will open, from there you can tick the 'Show post counts' box to display the post count of the categories.

[image: Screenshot2]

Answer (score 1):

```
class Shaka_Categories_Widget extends WP_Widget{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'shaka_categories_widget', // Base ID
            'Shaka Categories', // Name
            array('description' => __( 'Displays post Categories with counts'))
           );
    }
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        //$instance['post_type'] = strip_tags($new_instance['post_type']);
        //$instance['numberOfListings'] = strip_tags($new_instance['numberOfListings']);
        return $instance;
    }
    function form($instance) {
        if( $instance) {
            $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
        } else {
            $title = '';
        }
        ?>
            <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title', 'sim_most_viewed'); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
            </p>

        <?php
    }
    function widget($args, $instance) {
        extract( $args );
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);

        echo $before_widget;
        if ( $title ) {
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        }
        $this->getMostViewedListings();
        echo $after_widget;
    }
    function getMostViewedListings() { //html
        $args = array(
        'type' => 'post'
        );
        $categories = get_categories($args);
        //echo "<pre>";var_dump($categories);echo "</pre>";
        if($categories){
            echo "<ul>";
            foreach($categories as $cat){
                echo "<li><a href='".site_url().'/category/'.$cat->slug."'  class='cat-item cat-item-".$cat->term_id."'>".$cat->name." <span class='post-count'>".$cat->count."</span></a></li>";
            }   
            echo "</ul>";
        }
    }


} //end class

register_widget('Shaka_Categories_Widget');
```